# Cython reading in files in parallel and bypassing GIL

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cython

Trying to figure out how to use Cython to bypass the GIL and load files parallelly for IO bound tasks. For now I have the following Cython code trying to load files n0.npy, n1.py ... n100.npy

```
def foo_parallel():
    cdef int i

    for i in prange(100, nogil=True, num_threads=8):
        with gil:
            np.load('n'+str(i)+'.npy')

    return []

def foo_serial():
    cdef int i

    for i in range(100):
        np.load('n'+str(i)+'.npy')

    return []
```

I'm not noticing a significant speedup - does anyone have any experience with this?

Edit: I'm getting around 900ms parallely vs 1.3 seconds serially. Would expect more speedup given 8 threads

Comment: `np.load` loads and creates a `numpy` array, and thus cannot release the GIL, http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#acquiring-and-releasing-the-gil

Answer (score 1):

As the comment  states you can't use NumPy with gil and expect it to become parallel.  You need C or C++ level file operations to do this.  See this post here for a potential solution http://www.code-corner.de/?p=183

I.e. adapt this to your problem: `file_io.pyx` I'd post it here but can't figure out how on my cell.  Add `nogil` to the end of the `cdef` statement there and call the function from a `cpdef foo_parallel` defined function within your `prange` loop.  Use the `read_file` not the slow one and change it to `cdef`.  Please post benchmarks after doing so as I'm curious and have no computer on vacation.